# Pivot column1 into the headings and column2 as rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm very new to using pivot in SQL and would like to try and pivot this.
Any help would be appreciated. (Northwind Database)

I'm trying to pivot lastname above the TotalOrders.
Last names are in column1 and the total orders are in column2

```
lastname  TotalOrders
---------------------
Buchanan     42

Callahan    104

Davolio     123

Dodsworth    43

Fuller       96

King         72

Leverling   127

Peacock     156

Suyama       67
```

/*Trying to do: */

```
[lastname]   [Buchanan]  [Callahan]...

TotalOrders     42           104   ...
```

/*This is what I have so far.*/
[Code]

```
SELECT lastname, COUNT(*) TotalOrders
    FROM employees join orders
    ON employees.employeeid = orders.employeeid
    GROUP BY lastname

PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(TotalOrders)
  FOR lastname IN ([Buchanan], [Callahan], [Davolio], [Dodsworth]
                  ,[Fuller], [King], [Leverling], [Peacock], [Suyama])

) AS P;
```

[/Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Put the join query in a subquery and use MAX (or MIN) in the pivot.

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT lastname, COUNT(*) TotalOrders
    FROM employees join orders
    ON employees.employeeid = orders.employeeid
    GROUP BY lastname
) t
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(TotalOrders)
  FOR lastname IN ([Buchanan], [Callahan], [Davolio], [Dodsworth]
                  ,[Fuller], [King], [Leverling], [Peacock], [Suyama])

) AS P;
```

Comment: Thank you so much GurV! Your awesome! Than you once again!